"ListKeys" permission on this Bing resource is required for the demo to run
I am trying Bing Web Search API. After reaching a total cost of $202, I encountered a permission error from http request.
Error calling Bing API 401 Client Error: PermissionDenied for url: https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD&mkt=zh-CN&count=3&cc=CN

When I use the try me tab in the Azure console, the result returns
"ListKeys" permission on this Bing resource is required for the demo to run.

"ListKeys" permission error screenshot
Though the error messages are too ambiguous to know what happened, I wonder if it is related to the billing issues? I added a credit card but it does not show in Cost Management: <MyBingSearch> subscription, which says Payment methods and credits are only available for billing accounts, billing profiles, and pay-as-you-go subscriptions. Please change to a supported scope.
Is there anything wrong with the payment?
I also failed to enable Bing Statistics as suggested. Here is the screenshot.
Enabled failed for resource.

To resolve the error, try enabling Bing Statistics and check again. Refer this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/116175#issuecomment-1793686224

Thank you, I tried to enable it but got an error message, which shows "Enabled failed for resource /subscriptions/{my-id}/resourceGroups/{my-subscription-name}/..."

Could you check and confirm whether your subscription is active or not? "After reaching a total cost of $202" means, any credits left in your subscription?

I regenerated the keys and the problem is solved now.

@Zhengning how?

It could be because the Pricing Tier you selected does not support the Bing query type you perform.  I put together this table



Pricing Tier
Price per 1000 calls
Calls per second
Video Search
Image Search
News Search
Web Search
Entity Search
Auto-suggest
Spell Check
Related Search
Visual Search
Local Business Search
URL Preview




F1 Free
1000 calls per month
3
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
Y
N
N


S1 Standard
$25 USD per 1000 calls
250
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
N
N


S2 Standard
$15 USD per 1000 calls
100
N
N
N
Y
N
Y
Y
N
N
N
N


S3 Standard
$18 USD per 1000 calls
100
N
Y
N
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
N


S4 Standard
$18 USD per 1000 calls
100
Y
N
N
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
N


S5 Standard
$18 USD per 1000 calls
100
N
N
Y
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
N


S6 Standard
$15 USD per 1000 calls
100
N
N
N
Y
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N


S7 Standard
$20 USD per 1000 calls
150
Y
Y
N
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
N


S8 Standard
$22 USD per 1000 calls
150
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
N


S9 Standard
$15 USD per 1000 calls
30
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
N
Y
N
N


S15 Standard
$28 USD per 1000 calls
250
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
N
N


S16 Standard
$200 USD per 1000 calls
250
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
N
N



